# Include a DLL in python module (pypi)

Tags: python, dll, module, pypi

I have python module that wraps functions from a DLL in the same directory, and loads the library using ctypes.

```
__lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("deviceSys.dll")
```

Here's my directory Layout:

```
deviceSys
      - wrapper.py
      - deviceSys.dll
      - __init__.py
```

I'm following the package guidelines, but I'm not sure how to load the dll once my code is a module on PyPi. For instance, if I use ctypes to load the library, it produces an error, because it's searching locally:
 `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

I need to somehow embed my dll or search for the file within included resources for the package. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to add the DLL to the `package_data` in the `setup.py`:

```
include_package_data=True,
package_data={"devsys": ['deviceSystem.dll']},
```

To get the file from within `wrapper.py` use the following:

```
dir = os.path.dirname(sys.modules["devsys"].__file__)
path = os.path.join(dir, "deviceSystem.dll")
__lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
```